# How to plot data over a non-rectangular region in Octave?

Tags: plot, octave, visualization

I have three arrays of equal size: `x`, `y`, `z`. I want to plot `z` over `x`, `y`. Problems is, those `x` and `y` do not represent a rectangular region, such as what would be in case of using `meshgrid` function.

I know I can use something like `scatter`, but that would graphically only give me the points themselves. What I want is the filled, smoothed picture. So as opposed to this created by `scatter`:

[image]

I would like something like this:

[image]

Any suggestion how this can be done? I have a feeling the data must be smoothed out somehow via interpolation or something else prior to plotting which itself should be simple.

Comment: You're on the right track. I would use meshgrid anyway to create a rectangular grid, interpolate the z values on it, and then set to NaN all values outside your actual region. NaN values are always represented in white, regardless of the colormap that you will use.

Comment: @MatteoV with octave the `NaN` value usually take the color of the last element in the colormap.

Comment: @obchardon thanks for the correction, that just refered to Matlab only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `griddata()` to interpolate your `x`,`y` data on a regular grid and then you can use `imagesc()` to plot the result.

Here is a minimal example with a basic circle:

```
% INPUT
x = cos(0:0.1:2*pi);
y = sin(0:0.1:2*pi);
z = (0:0.1:2*pi);

% Create a regular grid that have the same boundary as your x,y data
[xx,yy] = meshgrid(linspace(-1,1,100),linspace(-1,1,100));
% Grid interpolation 
zz = griddata (x, y, z, xx, yy);
% Plot
imagesc(zz)
colormap ([jet(); 1 1 1]);  % I add a last [1 1 1] triplet to set the NaN color to white.
```

[image]

Noticed that this will only works if you keep the default interpolation method (which is a linear interpolation). The other method (cubic and nearest) will extend the domain of definition by analytic continuation.

Comment: This seems like a great solution! However, when trying to reproduce exactly your case, my background is black. Any way to make it white?

Comment: Mhhhh you're probably using another octave version than mine... you can try to use `colormap ([1 1 1; jet()])` instead.

Comment: Tried it myself, no difference. Should I maybe try to replace NaN values in zz with something that would give me white color? But what would it be for the jet colormap?

Comment: if you do something like: `zz(isnan(zz)) = max(zz(:))` with `colormap ([jet(); 1 1 1]);` it should work.

Comment: that there has been some work on griddata in the last year that didn't make it into v6.2, but has been pushed to the codebase for v7. v6.2 only implements linear and nearest neighbor interpolation. cubic produces a 'not available yet' error. A matlab compatible 'v4'  Biharmonic Spline Interpolation Green's Function method has been added for v7 along with bug fixes to griddata, griddata3 and griddatan. 'cubic' and 'natural' interpolations are still pending.  if needed, the new functions can be manually obtained from https://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/bb50407f9c60/scripts/geometry

Comment: @obchardon After carefully examining this trick with replacing NaN, I see that there are white spots on the figure. They correspond to the points of the maximal value of the data. So this replaces both the background and the maximal values on the data itself, which is bad. Is there a way to avoid the latter?

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the best approach would be some slight modification to what [obchardon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67282555/7856183) is proposing:

instead of the lines

```
imagesc(zz)
colormap ([jet(); 1 1 1]);
```

do this:

```
surf(xx, yy, zz);
shading interp;
colormap("jet");
```

This eliminates the problem with the black background. Then all it takes is just to rotate the camera with a mouse so that the 3d surface looked like 2d from above.